# Python - scope variables returning none

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

I'm trying to build a grid based of a function i'm creating. I have assigned inner variables one for the

```
grid1(number):
    D = ('-' * number)
    S = (' ' * number)
    H = print('+'+ D +'+' + D + '+')
    V = print('|'+ S + '|' + S + '|' '\n')
    print( H '\n' (V * number) + H '\n'+ (V * number) + H)
```

Basically im trying to create a grid that is 2 x 2, when it prints the V variable a second time, or even the next H, the variable returns as None. To my knowledge, I did not create an iterator, therefore the variable should still be assigned.

Am i missing something with scope variables ?

Comment: `print` does not return anything, which is in fact `None`. Could you please fix that example code, it looks completely broken.

Comment: I just want to print those variables in sequence, however it works the first time but the second time around it does not.  Im trying to understand why so i can fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted to assign the strings to H and V, then use those again in the next print statement. In that case you need to remove the first two `print` statements and only do the assignment to the variables. With some other fixes, this results in:

```
def grid1(number):
    D = ('-' * number)
    S = (' ' * number)
    H = '+'+ D +'+' + D + '+'
    V = '|'+ S + '|' + S + '|' '\n'
    print( H + '\n' + (V * number) + H + '\n' + (V * number) + H)
```

Which leads to for example:

```
>>> grid1(3)
+---+---+
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
+---+---+
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
+---+---+
```